# ApplicationBar custom button

Tags: windows-phone-8

The stock `ApplicationBar` only seems to support circle icons with optional text menu items. I'd like to get the design that you can see when you go to Settings -> email+accounts -> add an account and select Google, Facebook or Hotmail. There is one rectangular "next" or "sign in" button. Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: You should also mind the Windws Phone 8 Design Guidlines http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202915(v=VS.92).aspx. Rectangular buttons are not regular to these.

Comment: Was looking for the exact same thing and ended up putting an "arrow to the right"-icon in the appbar. It's a pitty wp doesn't offer some controls which are part of the natural design pattern of the general os (in this case a login dialog)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The is no support for rectangular buttons in the application bar in the SDK. You can fairly easily create a similar effect using a XAML `Grid` at the bottom of your page.

However watch out that if you use a `TextBox` to enter text on your page, then the onscreen keyboard can cover your buttons, confusing your users. In that case you're better sticking to normal app bar circular buttons.